# How can I add the current directory to `PYTHONPATH` automatically?

Tags: python, elpy

I use `elpy` and I am not able to use relative paths to access files because the `PYTHONPATH` doesn't include the directory I'm in by default. I may have set it up wrong in `elpy-config`. Here are my paths by default after using `pprint.pprint(sys.path)`:

```
['',
 '/usr/lib/python310.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.10',
 '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
 '/home/steve/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages',
 '/home/steve/Python/']
```

I was adding the path every project using `os.chdir()` but this didn't work for modules so
I have been manually appending the path that I'm working in every new project I start by using `sys.path.append()` and this works fine. How can I have the current directory I'm in added to the path's without having to append it every time?

```
Emacs.............: 27.1
Elpy..............: 1.35.0
Virtualenv........: venv (/home/steve/.virtualenvs/venv/)
Interactive Python: python3 3.10.4 (/home/steve/.virtualenvs/venv/bin/python3)
RPC virtualenv....: rpc-venv (/home/steve/.emacs.d/.local/etc/elpy/rpc-venv)
 Python...........: python 3.10.4 (/home/steve/.emacs.d/.local/etc/elpy/rpc-venv/bin/python)
 Jedi.............: 0.18.1
 Autopep8.........: 1.6.0
 Yapf.............: 0.32.0
 Black............: 22.3.0
Syntax checker....: flake8 (/home/steve/.virtualenvs/venv/bin/flake8)
```

Comment: I am not familiar with `elpy`, but using `PYTHONPATH` is quite out of fashion these days. Almost everyone I know uses a tool like `pipenv` or `poetry` to run their project in a "virtual environment", and I know that there are Emacs packages to support that style of work.

Comment: Adding to the previous comment, check out the [pyvenv](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/pyvenv) emacs package.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted `__pycache__` and `.mypycache` from a parent directory, now my path is functioning as expected.